# Cannot bundle SignalR JavaScript using ScriptBundle class with optimizations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, scriptbundle

After installing the SignalR NuGet package:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -pre
```

I get the following files:

```
jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc2.js
jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc2.min.js
```

I register the bundle:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery.signalR").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-{version}.js"));
```

In my view I call:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery.signalR")
```

It all works during development, but once I enable:

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

The bundle fails to render the script.

I've also tried:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery.signalR").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-{version}-rc2.js"))
```

which is a bit useless, since the whole point of using {version} is to be ready for future releases, and the next release is getting rid of the "-rc2" bit.

How can I effectively use wild card matching to my advantage to match the script:

```
jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc2.js
```

in development, and

```
jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc2.min.js
```

in production, while at the same time being prepared for a future update of SignalR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `{version}` moniker in bundling does not work for pre-release scripts. To work with pre-release scripts you can use the following registration

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery.signalR").Include(
        "~/Scripts/jquery.signalR*"));
```

Comment: Thank you. This great info. Where in the documentation could I find more detailed explanation? 

I was going by this article. 
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

Is there a more detailed explanation of what patterns and wildcards I can use inside ScriptBundle.Include?